# How can I add jQuery UI effects to buttons loaded from a plain HTML file?

Tags: jquery, json, html, jquery-ui, razor

I am dynamically changing the contents on my web site in three different ways:

```
0) Reading json files via jQuery's getJSON('bla.json');
1) Retrieving jsonized C#/Razor classes via jQuery's getJSON('bla.cshtml');
2) Loading the html from a file via $('#divName').load('bla.html');
```

They all work fine, except that the latter does not decorate/spiffify my buttons.

I thought maybe it was because the HTML file had no knowledge of jQuery and jQuery UI, so I added these lines to the top of the page:

```
<link href="~/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

...but it makes no difference.

To see the effect "live" go to my site at www.awardwinnersonly.com - the Books > Spurs (Westerns) awards (just started - only one book so far) is the one that uses the Load('bla.html') approach; Hugos uses the cshtml, and all the others are getting raw json files.

Here is the entire code persuant to Spurs:

HTML (I took out the lines shown above, as they didn't help any):

```
<div class="yearBanner">2013</div><section class="wrapper" ><a id="mainImage" class="floatLeft" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0085DOE2O" rel="nofollow noreferrer"" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B0085DOE2O.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg"alt="Tucker's Reckoning by Ralph Compton and Matthew Mayo book cover"></img></a><div id="prizeCategory" class="category">Best Short Novel</div><br/><cite id="prizeTitle" >Tucker's 
Reckoning</cite><br/><div id="prizeArtist" class="author">Ralph Compton and Matthew Mayo</div><br/><button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0085DOE2O" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >Kindle</a></button><button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0451415612" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow" >Hardcover</a></button><button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0451465482" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >Paperback</a></button></section>
```

CSS:

```
.yearBanner {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Candara, Calibri, Consolas, sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.floatLeft {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

section.wrapper {
    /* this may need to be wider when landscape cover img is used */
    min-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    width: 160px;
}

.categorySmallerFont {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: Orange;
    width: 160px;
}

cite {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, serif;
    color: Yellow;
    width: 160px;
}

.author, .artist, .person {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    width: 160px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function getSpurs() {
    $('#BooksContent').load('Content/spurFirstPage.html');
    $('button').button();
    var $largest = 0;
    $(".wrapper").each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > $largest) {
            $largest = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $(".wrapper").css("height", $largest);
}
```

Can I reference _SiteLayout.cshtml from my html file, or how can I incorporate the desired jQuery theme to my buttons?

Comment: I realized all of those IDs in the HTML are worthless and have stripped them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is an ajax function. Basically, when you use

```
$('#BooksContent').load('Content/spurFirstPage.html');
$('button').button();
```

the buttons from the page have not yet loaded, so nothing happens.

Simply use a [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function):

```
$('#BooksContent').load('Content/spurFirstPage.html', function(){
     $('button').button();
});
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Perferct, thanks. I updated my site and now it looks more beautiful than I don't know what.